# Autofac, Owin and memory leaks. Is autofac leaking with owin?

Tags: memory-leaks, asp.net-web-api2, owin, autofac

Recently I realized there is a leak in my Web API application based on Owin and Autofac. The leak is not permanent but memory kept longer than per request. Here's the deal:

**1-)** By default Web API uses buffered responses and the runtime keeps *OverlappedData* structure up to 40 instances as an object pool even after the response is returned. (For performance reasons I guess)

**2-)** Each *OverlappedData* structure keeps the *OwinContext* alive (only 40 at a time probably for pooling)

**3-)** Because *OwinContext* is alive, the associated *Autofac* container per request scope is kept alive though the container itself is disposed.

**4-)** Even if *Autofac* container is disposed, it is keeping the objects in its sharedInstances dictionary.

Hence the memory leak. A workaround is to use streaming instead of buffering and then there is no *OverlappedData*. But I am curious about another solution.

Another weird thing is if an Autofac container is disposed it is still keeping the data in its dictionary. It should set the dictionary to null instead! Any ideas ?

Comment: "Even if Autofac container is disposed". Do you mean you have one container per request?

Comment: @Steven, Yes. Correct.

Comment: You should not create one container per request. Creating containers has a lot of overhead; both in memory and CPU. There's the registration, expression tree compilation, delegate generation, JITting. Besides, Autofac [is thread-safe](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/concurrency.html#service-resolution).

Comment: @Steve, at each request a child container is created from root. There's only one global root.

Comment: Ah okay. That's good.

Comment: Is it a leak or just bloat? If the `OverlappedData` pool is only a finite number of items, it sounds like more memory is used than necessary, but it's not _leaking_ (ie, unrecoverable), it's just _bloated_. (Not that it doesn't still warrant attention, just that bloat generally doesn't crash the app.)

Comment: [I filed an issue on your behalf to look deeper into this.](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/807)

Comment: @TravisIllig, yeah it won't increase in definitely. But the memory can be exhausted quickly depending on what you hold. The issue you filed is right on the spot! Also another issue needs to be filed out, is owin integration should remove the life time from owincontext on its disposal.