# WCF client resolved by Autofac causes memory leak in Web API app

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I've got an issue in a ASP.NET Web API (2.2 aka 5.2.3). I'm also using Autofac 4.2.0, Autofac.Wcf 4.0.0 and Autofac.WebApi2 4.0.1.
The WCF service dependency is configured this way (same as in the [docs](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/wcf.html)):

```
builder.Register(c => new ChannelFactory<ISchedulerWcfService>("SchedulerService"))
   .SingleInstance();
```

builder.Register(c => c.Resolve`<ChannelFactory<ISchedulerWcfService>>`().CreateChannel())
      .As`<ISchedulerWcfService>`()
      .UseWcfSafeRelease();

And in Web.config:

```
<bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
         <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000" maxStringContentLength="8192000" maxArrayLength="10000000" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      </binding>
   </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
     <endpoint address="http://localhost:8756/SchedulerService/" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Interfaces.WcfServicesInterfaces.ISchedulerWcfService" name="SchedulerService" />
</client>
```

The service is consumed then with standard constructor injection. 
I'm assuming, that, the usage of UseWcfSafeRelease() extension method makes Autofac properly dispose of the service proxies. But actually, when i profile the app I get thousands of ServiceChannel object hierarchies after a reasonable number of Web API requests, which use the WCF service: [image: screen] (sorry for the photo, screenshot uploads are prohibited at work).

So now I don't know how to fix this issue. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Or maybe someone had experienced the same problem. Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may read like a comment, but it's sort of a long comment, or at least some rambling pointers. Stick with me.

**It looks like your WCF client stuff is correctly wired up.** Don't worry about that part. That looks right.

**`UseWcfSafeRelease` is there to stop exceptions from channel closing.** It runs *instead* of calling `IDisposable.Dispose` on the channel. There's not much code in it; [it's probably better if you just look at it](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Wcf/blob/develop/src/Autofac.Integration.Wcf/RegistrationExtensions.cs#L54).

So there's a little reassurance/confirmation that, well, so far, so good.

Now, as to the leak, as it were...

**There's not enough here to really tell exactly what's going on.** Given the problem isn't with how you've registered your WCF client, it means there's something else going on.

The stack on the *left* looks normal. You'll notice from the bottom-up that it basically reads, "The single instance of the HttpConfiguration, which is attached to the Autofac dependency resolver, resolved a singleton channel factory that opened a channel and is holding onto it." That's pretty standard. You can see that it's a singleton because the "rootLifetimeScope" is in the trace, things are getting added to a "sharedInstances" dictionary, and so on.

The stack on the *right* is what I'd be looking at harder. I'm guessing the whole stack isn't shown there because I don't actually see Autofac anywhere in that stack. That's the stack with your controller in it, though, which implies that's likely where the individual channels are being generated and held. Of course, that would also potentially imply your controller and the whole stack of objects is being held, which should also appear somewhere in there.

**It'd be good to see which stack has the objects in it.** Here's why:

Knowing how [Autofac handles disposal](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html) we know that disposable objects or things with `OnRelease` handlers will get **held until the owning lifetime scope is disposed.** That's why [you should always resolve from a lifetime scope rather than the root container](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/best-practices/index.html) whenever possible - so disposables won't be held for the life of the application.

Soooo...

**Look for application-level things resolving from the container.** For example, I've seen classic ASP.NET applications try to resolve from the container using service location in an `HttpModule`. That's not good. I'm not saying that's what you're doing, I'm saying be mindful and look in the app for things being resolved from the application container.

**Is this an issue with Web API response buffering?** [We saw a question recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40290851/autofac-owin-and-memory-leaks-is-autofac-leaking-with-owin) where someone found that Web API and OWIN keep some context things around for too long - including the lifetime scope reference. [Based on that](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/807) we're doing a little more proactive cleaning and [that was released in Autofac v4.2.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac/4.2.1).

**Is something holding onto the request lifetime scope too long?** For example...

- **Do you have something holding the `HttpRequestMessage` too long?** In Web API, the request lifetime scope flows with the `HttpRequestMessage`. If the request message doesn't get disposed, the lifetime scope won't get disposed, so the WCF proxy won't get disposed.
- **Do you have something resolving and/or holding the `ILifetimeScope` for the request too long?** Similar to the above note about the `HttpRequestMessage`, I've seen folks sometimes inject an `ILifetimeScope` into a class so they can do service location.

Those are some things to look for.

Finally, a tip:

**Rather than inject `ISchedulerWcfService` into your controller, consider `Func<ISchedulerWcfService>`.** I say that for two reasons:

1. If your controller has actions where it *doesn't* need the service proxy, this will stop it from being proactively instantiated. If you need the proxy, call the automatically injected factory function. If not, no worries - and no additional memory usage.
2. If your service proxy faults the channel you can't use it again... and without the factory function, there's no way to get yourself a new one. Not a big deal if you're only making one service call per controller action, but if you want to allow for retries, call multiple things, etc., you'll want that factory available.

That's long, and it may not solve the problem, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer made me debug and think a bit further. First I upgraded the version to 4.2.1 but it didn't help. And then I realised I had a singleton reference of model processing logics class, which was opening the channels within its own lifetime scope. So I fixed it by wrapping the call into using(scope.BeginLifetimeScope()){}.

I'm also considering to follow your advice to inject Func<ISchedulerWcfService>.

Thanks again for the detailed answer and big up for Autofac!

Comment: So glad I could help! Don't forget to mark it as the answer, if you wouldn't mind.